# Counting traversed arcs on routes to write attributes using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, overlapping-features

I have number of persons located on a road network and I have calculated their shortest distance to a particular location.

From the routes output created from Closest Facility can I

1. break the routes down into the individual arcs traversed by each person?
2. assign each arc a count attribute indicating the number of individuals who use that arc to get to their destination?

I am using Network Analyst in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do what I think you want to do then yes, you can, but Network Analyst is not required (and I'm not aware of a way to use it to do so off the top of my head).

1. Export your route layer to a feature class.
2. Intersect that layer to the lines that make up your network (you may
   need to export them as Intersect won't run on a network feature). The resulting dataset should have each segment that corresponds with
   a route, and each segment will be duplicated once for every route
   that passes over it.
3. Using Summarize on the segment ID in the
   attribute table or the Summary Statistics tool should then give you
   a count of how many times each segment is used.

Comment: I tested on a sample data set and this worked exactly as described. Thank you!