# OD cost matrix network analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I would like to know if it's possible for my OD cost matrix to know which segments are been used to get to the destination. In other words I would like to know which network segments have been used and how many times to reach my destination?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Per the [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000004r000000):

> The closest facility and OD cost matrix solvers perform very similar
>   analyses; the main difference, however, is in the output and the
>   computation speed. OD cost matrix generates results more quickly but
>   cannot return the true shapes of routes or their driving directions.
>   It is designed to quickly solve large M x N problems and, as a result,
>   does not internally contain the information required to generate route
>   shapes and driving directions. Alternatively, the closest facility
>   solver returns routes and directions but performs the analysis more
>   slowly than the OD cost matrix solver. If you need driving directions
>   or true shapes of routes, use the closest facility solver; otherwise,
>   use the OD cost matrix solver to reduce the computation time.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how do i set arcgis to mesure all my " facilities" in one request when i use " solve" ?

Comment: It solve actully all the ittinarie from my " facilities " to the destination, but dosent look like to be possible to know witch street network are the most used when generating the network... ?

Comment: If not, any other solution to my problem? thanks!

Comment: @SimonGIS You can't do it with a single solve; you have to create a script or model. See my answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124445/network-analyst-question-summing-multiple-routes/124906#124906 which also links to another question with a method to figure out how many times any given road segment is traversed. The tutorial [exercise six](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Exercise_6_Creating_a_model_for_route_analysis/004700000061000000/) may help you with automating the closest facility solves.

Comment: ... hours later .. I use  Copy Traversed Source Features tool, it work great! thanks gor the help!

Comment: So my above *comment* isn't correct. You can get the routes from all incidents to *all* facilities in a single Closest Facility solve. I'd forgotten there is a 'number of facilities to find' parameter for cases like you want to find the three nearest fire stations to incidents and not just one. All you have to do is set that parameter to equal number of facilities and you get the equivalent of OD Cost Matrix with actual routes. @SimonGIS sorry if the earlier version of this comment was confusing. The answer itself is still correct.