# Summing number of pedestrians who use route using ArcMap and Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

I am using ArcMap 10.6 and Network Analyst.

I have multiple points (origins) which will travel to one destination. every point has number of people who will travel to that point. I used closest facility as a solution here.

How can I calculate how many people in every segment?

For example, if segment A has 100 people and segment B has 20 people and they intersect/combined into one segment. This new segment should have a value of 120 people. I tried to benefit from  [Summing multiple routes using ArcGIS Network Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124445) but that has not helped so far.

Any idea?

Comment: To clarify, I have succeeded to find how many times every segment have been traversed by points. Now , every point has number of people say like point 1 has 100 people and point 2 has 200 people etc. suppose that Area A has 100 points who travelled to destination and every point has 100 people. Converseley, Area B has 10 points and every point has 10K people. in this case the most traversed segments are from Area A rather than Area B. For that reason, I need a way to count the value of every point rather than deal with the point itself? Any idea pls. I hope my question is clear and find answer